# How can I increase the MAX_PATH_LENGTH in a freeBSD system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, freebsd, system-calls

I am writing a 'find' like utility to search some particular files in a freebsd based system. The stat() call in freeBSD 9 can accept paths with length 1024 chars, though linux supports upto 4K char paths.

The system itself has a filesystem other than freeBSD's (its a commercial OS) and that filesystem has a very high limit on MAX_PATH_LENGTH.

If some user mounted a volume on linux and created a directory hierarchy with path length greater than 1K, then though the filesystem will support it, the freeBSD lstat/stat calls will fail.

Is there a way around, or can I get this limit increased somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by upping the value for [PATH_MAX in /usr/src/sys/sys/syslimits.h](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.0.0/sys/sys/syslimits.h?revision=229286&view=markup#l63) and doing a full rebuild of the entire system (kernel, libraries, and any installed software that uses PATH_MAX, MAXPATHLEN, or MAXINTERP).  Just make sure to [keep it under 64k](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.0.0/sys/sys/param.h?revision=229286&view=markup#l236).

If you do go this route, avoid using binary packages (like via pkg, portmaster, or portupgrade).  Stick to compiling and installing out of /usr/ports, and you'll be fine.